# MVC Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

i'm trying to implement windows authentication in a MVC application but I'm having some trouble.

I had create a new user called "test" and i gave him all the permissions to the folder in IIS

In the web config i wrote this code:

```
 <system.web>
     <authentication mode="Windows"/>
     <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
     </authorization>
...
```

I i set the attribute authorized on the products controller as follows

```
[Authorize(Users="test")]
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    { ...
```

i also try only

```
[Authorize]
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    {...
```

When I try to enter it asks me constantly credentials without give me permission to enter even if username and password are correct

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: use [System.Web.Mvc.Authorize] for authorization

Comment: i already have the using directive System.Web.Mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these two solutions one at a time and see which one fixes it.

1) [Configure windows authentication in IIS.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

2) Follow [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chiranth/archive/2014/04/17/setting-up-kerberos-authentication-for-a-website-in-iis.aspx) guide till step 3. Set it to NTLM and attempt to access the site. If not switch to Negotiate.

These are usually the steps I need to perform if I have odd issues with windows authentication.

Comment: I will after work, and thank you. I haven't done that yet, so probably the issue./ I will try after work, and update the answer accordingly.