# Hosting MVC Web app on IIS using Windows Authentication

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis, web-applications

I am trying to host my web application on IIS using Windows Authentication for the first time. I have updated the web.conf file to use this method, and also the site in IIS to use this method also. When locally debugging, this works correctly. When I try to manually deploy the app to IIS though, it does not authenticate. Can someone help explain if I missed a step, or a quick brief process of step by step guide of doing this, so I can see if I missed some minor step or not? I have Google it everywhere, but do not see a difference in what I have done. I cannot post the IIS settings on here, but will explain. I take the site DLL's, and place them in the folder for the site. I can then go to it in the browser, but never authenticate.  Thanks for future hekp.

Comment: What do you mean by it does not authenticate? Any error messages displayed?

Comment: No, no errors I can see. It only states Access Denied or due to invalid credentials. I know this is hard to troubleshoot with no view of it, and appologize. Hoping someone will say the steps, and maybe see that I mised one.

Comment: See the second point in [this response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29200897/1453651). Its a gotcha in my organization.